# Tensorflow dependency causing Heroku app to exceed maximum slug size

Tags: tensorflow, heroku, deployment, web-applications

I'm deploying an app on Heroku which has tensorflow as a dependency, but installing tensorflow causes it to exceed maximum slug size which is capped at 500M. I know this because I can push without tensorflow in requirements.txt. Heroku documentation says use .slugignore file to ignore static files or dependencies not being used, but tensorflow is absolutely required or the app will not actually run...I have to include it. How can I get around this?

```
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:  !     Compiled slug size: 610.3M is too large (max is 500M).
remote:  !     See: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-size
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to safe-fjord-13722.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/safe-fjord-13722.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/safe-fjord-13722.git
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still have problems deploying a deep learning model to Heroku, it is essential to remember that TensorFlow 2.0 is ~500 MB for some reason, while earlier versions are much smaller. Using a previous version of the TensorFlow will reduce the slug size considerably. Try to use TensorFlow 1 it will reduce your model size by 50% or more

Slug size is limited to 500MB as stated here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#slug-size

Comment: That fixed it! Everything still works fine with the earlier version. Thank you!